# Big O Comparison with exponential functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, data-structure

I know the question sounds easy but I am still confused with that... Say

1. $$A = 7^n; B=7^{n+log(3n)}$$
2. $$C = 2^{7n}; D = 2^{n}$$
   Then, I believe A=O(B) and C=Ω(D) right? However, I am struggling with another exceptional case. Here is the problem.
   Okay, I just apply the definitions of big O notation but I see there are several exceptional cases. Say if $$X=3^n$$ and $$Y=2^n$$, then X is not a member of the Big O family of Y. This is because we cannot find a constant k to satisfy the condition stated in the definition of Big O family. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your work/thinking?

Comment: Okay, I just apply the definitions of big O notation but I see there are several exceptional cases. Say if $$X = 3^n$$ and $$Y = 2^n$$, then X is not a member of the Big O family of Y.

Comment: You should add this to your question Frederick just copy past.

Comment: @user577215664 I am sorry about that. I have edited the question.

Comment: This is better +1

Comment: @MichaelBurr Prof. Burr, could u please be so kind to provide me some of the ideas of it?